# Does NumPy have a function equivalent to Matlab's buffer?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, buffer

I see there is an `array_split` and `split` [methods](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) but these are not very handy when you have to split an array of length which is not integer multiple of the chunk size. Moreover, these method’s input is the number of slices rather than the slice size. I need something more like Matlab's [buffer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/buffer.html) method which is more suitable for signal processing.

For example, if I want to buffer a signals to chunks of size 60 I need to do: `np.vstack(np.hsplit(x.iloc[0:((len(x)//60)*60)], len(x)//60))` which is cumbersome.

Comment: Did you try `np.split`? It splits at indices specified, so should take care of irregular intervals. We just need to create those indices using range.

Comment: Or maybe this helps https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2006-November/009962.html and the code at https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/attachments/20061119/292f81e3/attachment.py

Comment: A quick glance at the `buffer` doc reminds me of `numpy` `stride_tricks.as_strided`, especially in its ability to handler overlaps and skips.  But that may be too powerful, and dangerous, for this case.

Comment: `x.reshape(-1,60)` will break `x` into equal size rows of 60 items.  If the length of `x` isn't a multiple of 60 you'll have to pad or truncate.  But the `vstack` requires that as well.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote the following routine to handle the use cases I needed, but I have not implemented/tested for "underlap".

Please feel free to make suggestions for improvement.

```
def buffer(X, n, p=0, opt=None):
    '''Mimic MATLAB routine to generate buffer array

    MATLAB docs here: https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/buffer.html

    Parameters
    ----------
    x: ndarray
        Signal array
    n: int
        Number of data segments
    p: int
        Number of values to overlap
    opt: str
        Initial condition options. default sets the first `p` values to zero,
        while 'nodelay' begins filling the buffer immediately.

    Returns
    -------
    result : (n,n) ndarray
        Buffer array created from X
    '''
    import numpy as np

    if opt not in [None, 'nodelay']:
        raise ValueError('{} not implemented'.format(opt))

    i = 0
    first_iter = True
    while i < len(X):
        if first_iter:
            if opt == 'nodelay':
                # No zeros at array start
                result = X[:n]
                i = n
            else:
                # Start with `p` zeros
                result = np.hstack([np.zeros(p), X[:n-p]])
                i = n-p
            # Make 2D array and pivot
            result = np.expand_dims(result, axis=0).T
            first_iter = False
            continue

        # Create next column, add `p` results from last col if given
        col = X[i:i+(n-p)]
        if p != 0:
            col = np.hstack([result[:,-1][-p:], col])
        i += n-p

        # Append zeros if last row and not length `n`
        if len(col) < n:
            col = np.hstack([col, np.zeros(n-len(col))])

        # Combine result with next row
        result = np.hstack([result, np.expand_dims(col, axis=0).T])

    return result
```

Comment: Worked for me with one minor tweak. Because I'm using Python 3 (my theory), the 'cols' variable was being truncated. Think this is due to the change in how Python 3 deals with multiplication. I cast the denominator to float in the equation calculating 'cols' and the output then matched Matlab's output exactly in my case.
`cols = int(np.ceil(len(x)/float((n-p))))`

Comment: Thanks. I am using Python 3 too, but I ended up not using this, so perhaps I just didn't notice that.

Comment: I think the output of your algorithm for `nodelay` test case does not match with the output of MATLAB algorithm.

Comment: You can try the following test case. It gives wrong output. `data = buffer(np.arange(1,31),7,3,'nodelay')`

Comment: I've taken a look and corrected the error you mentioned @Maxtron. Thanks!

Comment: Just a minor comment. The algorithm throws error when both `p=0` and `nodelay` options are selected. Test case: `data = buffer(np.arange(1,31),7,0,'nodelay')`

Comment: Right... it's sorted now. I obviously should have written tests for this, but I'll let others do that :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

```
def buffer(X = np.array([]), n = 1, p = 0):
    #buffers data vector X into length n column vectors with overlap p
    #excess data at the end of X is discarded
    n = int(n) #length of each data vector
    p = int(p) #overlap of data vectors, 0 <= p < n-1
    L = len(X) #length of data to be buffered
    m = int(np.floor((L-n)/(n-p)) + 1) #number of sample vectors (no padding)
    data = np.zeros([n,m]) #initialize data matrix
    for startIndex,column in zip(range(0,L-n,n-p),range(0,m)):
        data[:,column] = X[startIndex:startIndex + n] #fill in by column
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

This Keras function may be considered as a Python equivalent of MATLAB Buffer().

See the Sample Code :

```
import numpy as np
S = np.arange(1,99) #A Demo Array
```

[See Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KNCH.png)

```
import tensorflow.keras.preprocessing as kp
list(kp.timeseries_dataset_from_array(S, targets = None,sequence_length=7,sequence_stride=7,batch_size=5))
```

[See the Buffered Array Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hwjx.png)

Reference : [See This](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/timeseries/#timeseriesdatasetfromarray-function)

Answer (score 0):

Same as the other answer, but faster.

```
def buffer(X, n, p=0):

    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    x: ndarray
        Signal array
    n: int
        Number of data segments
    p: int
        Number of values to overlap

    Returns
    -------
    result : (n,m) ndarray
        Buffer array created from X
    '''
    import numpy as np

    d = n - p
    m = len(X)//d

    if m * d != len(X):
        m = m + 1

    Xn = np.zeros(d*m)
    Xn[:len(X)] = X

    Xn = np.reshape(Xn,(m,d))
    Xne = np.concatenate((Xn,np.zeros((1,d))))
    Xn = np.concatenate((Xn,Xne[1:,0:p]), axis = 1)

    return np.transpose(Xn[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

[ryanjdillon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943773/ryanjdillon)'s answer rewritten for significant performance improvement; it appends to a list instead of concatenating arrays, latter which copies the array iteratively and is much slower.

```py
def buffer(x, n, p=0, opt=None):
    if opt not in ('nodelay', None):
        raise ValueError('{} not implemented'.format(opt))

    i = 0
    if opt == 'nodelay':
        # No zeros at array start
        result = x[:n]
        i = n
    else:
        # Start with `p` zeros
        result = np.hstack([np.zeros(p), x[:n-p]])
        i = n-p
    # Make 2D array, cast to list for .append()
    result = list(np.expand_dims(result, axis=0))

    while i < len(x):
        # Create next column, add `p` results from last col if given
        col = x[i:i+(n-p)]
        if p != 0:
            col = np.hstack([result[-1][-p:], col])

        # Append zeros if last row and not length `n`
        if len(col):
            col = np.hstack([col, np.zeros(n - len(col))])

        # Combine result with next row
        result.append(np.array(col))
        i += (n - p)

    return np.vstack(result).T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def buffer(X, n, p=0):
'''
Parameters:
x: ndarray, Signal array, input a long vector as raw speech wav
n: int, frame length
p: int, Number of values to overlap
-----------
Returns:
result : (n,m) ndarray, Buffer array created from X
'''
import numpy as np
d = n - p
#print(d)
m = len(X)//d
c = n//d
#print(c)
if m * d != len(X):
    m = m + 1
#print(m)

Xn = np.zeros(d*m)
Xn[:len(X)] = X
Xn = np.reshape(Xn,(m,d))
Xn_out = Xn
for i in range(c-1):
    Xne = np.concatenate((Xn,np.zeros((i+1,d))))
    Xn_out = np.concatenate((Xn_out, Xne[i+1:,:]),axis=1)
#print(Xn_out.shape)  
if n-d*c>0:
    Xne = np.concatenate((Xn, np.zeros((c,d))))
    Xn_out = np.concatenate((Xn_out,Xne[c:,:n-p*c]),axis=1)

return np.transpose(Xn_out)
```

here is a improved code of Ali Khodabakhsh's sample code which is not work in my cases. Feel free to comment and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the execution time of the proposed answers, by running

```
x = np.arange(1,200000)
start = timer()
y = buffer(x,60,20)
end = timer()
print(end-start)
```

the results are:

Andrzej May, 0.005595300000095449

OverLordGoldDragon, 0.06954789999986133

ryanjdillon, 2.427092700000003

Answer (score 0):

Numpy probably doesn't have such a built-in function. However, both Pytorch and Tensorflow have it.The only difference is that input argument is "step" instead of "overlap". *(step = window length - overlap)*

**Pytorch**

torch.unfold has 3 input arguments ([ref](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.unfold.html#torch.Tensor.unfold)):

**dimension (int)** – dimension in which unfolding happens.

**size (int)** – the size of each slice that is unfolded *(window length)*

**step (int)** – the step between each slice*(window length - overlap)*

```
x = torch.arange(1., 8)
x.unfold(0, 2, 1)
```

Then you can simply change data type back to numpy:

```
x.numpy()
```

For tensorflow equivalent, you can check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/frame).